# How to chage the status of Blockdevice to Active?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, block-device

I have a couple of block devices in my pod and one of them is `InActive`. I want the both block devices to be active.

Currently the output looks like this:

```
>>> kubectl get bd

NAME                                           NODENAME   SIZE           CLAIMSTATE   STATUS     AGE

blockdevice-4c4d1bbe352afd256d995b8f4eec7fde   openebs    107373116928   Unclaimed    Inactive   19h
blockdevice-6a43814b120f763e15acd5152127a149   openebs    107374182400   Unclaimed    Active     62m
```

I want the bd - `blockdevice-4c4d1bbe352afd256d995b8f4eec7fde` to be Active as well.

I tried to run `kubectl describe bd` but still one remains `Inactive`.

Comment: Hi @ParthS007 Could you please edit your question with the output of `kubectl describe bd blockdevice-4c4d1bbe352afd256d995b8f4eec7fde` and also show us the yaml config of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the block device info with the following command:

```
kubectl edit bd blockdevice-4c4d1bbe352afd256d995b8f4eec7fde -n openebs
```